# Read Specific Columns from a pickle files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

So I know in Pandas, you can specific what columns to pull from a csv file to generate a DataFrame

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols=['a','b','c'])
```

How do you do this with a pickled file?

```
df = pd.read_pickle('data.pkl', usecols=['a','b','c'])
```

gives **TypeError: read_pickle() got an unexpected keyword argument 'usecols'**

I cant find the correct argument in the documentation

Comment: There are no parameters to select columns to read using `pd.read_pickle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since pickle files contain complete python objects I doubt you can select columns whilst loading them or atleast it seems pandas doesnt support that directly. But you can first load it completely and then filter for your columns as such:

```
df = pd.read_pickle('data.pkl')
df = df.filter(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

Comment: I am actually trying to avoid loading it in its entirety because it has an ungodly number of columns that I just don't need. I don't want to wast the memory since I am using a free trail of IBM Watson. It is a requirement for a class I am taking

Comment: If you can save the data as a .parquet you can have similar compression and speed AND you can read select columns